# how to split keyboard style change?

Tags: ios, ipad, split, keyboard

I want to make split keyboard background this way.

[image]

But now split keyboard appears this way.

[image]

Please answer.

Comment: what is background color?

Comment: do you mean, keyboard background color?

Comment: no i meant your view controller's color

Comment: Color is white. I wonder center color of keyboard at the first picture is controller's color Or keyboard backgound color?